# Align a layout on top, inside other layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have 2 fragments, the first had the second inside it. This is the first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_details_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetailTitle"
        style="@style/textTitleDetailStyle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailSubObjectFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetailButtonGo"
        style="@style/goButtonStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And inside the layout detailSubObjectFrame I had others fragments. In this specific case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sub_take_error_Layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/numberErrorLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.mypackage.NumberPickerCustom
            android:id="@+id/numberPickerCustomRandom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            max="100"
            min="1"
            value="30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moreText"
            style="@style/textOnSubmenu"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/moreErrorText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfQuestion"
            style="@style/textOnSubmenu"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/numberOfErrorQuestionText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfQuestionValue"
            style="@style/textOnSubmenu"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="6" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like that the layout "myLayoutTop", will be placed just below the textview of the first fragment fragmentDetailTitle. (Without moving the other layout from the center).
Like you can see I tried layout_alignParentTop but didn't work.
If needed I could totally change only the layout of the 2nd fragment, the constraint that I have is that numberErrorLayout should stay (like now) on the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the layout of detailSubObjectFrame in a FrameLayout and sub_take_error_Layout in a LinearLayout. After I used the attribute gravity for numberErrorLayout and myLayoutTop.